# Gstreamer HLSSink Pipeline Displays Black Frames in Safari

Tags: gstreamer, http-live-streaming, gstreamer-1.0, gst-launch-1.0

**This `get-launch-1.0` command line pipeline**: `gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=680 ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink location=junk2.%05d.ts playlist-location=junk2.m3u8`

**This server**: `python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000`

**This local url on Mac OS X Safari**: http://localhost:8000/junk2.m3u8

Appears to play in local Safari browser, but displays black frames. Why?

Note: python console output looks pretty happy, so all the paths are correct:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
Serving HTTP on 0.0.0.0 port 8000 ...
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2018 11:40:34] "GET /junk2.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2018 11:40:34] "GET /junk2.m3u8 HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2018 11:40:34] "GET /junk2.00001.ts HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Apr/2018 11:40:34] "GET /junk2.00000.ts HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Note: Also tried various options to the hlssink plugin without changes in behavior:

- `target-duration=2`
- `max-files=0`
- `playlist-length=0`

**Other Players**: Plays and displays correctly in VLC:
[image: VLC Playback]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `x264enc` selects the wrong profile. If you don't tell it what to use and in your use case with `videotestsrc` it will select a `4:4:4` color profile instead of `4:2:0`. A lot of decoders don't support this.

Tell `videotestsrc` to feed a `4:2:0` format instead:

```
gst-launch-1.0 videotestsrc num-buffers=680 ! video/x-raw, format=I420 ! x264enc ! mpegtsmux ! hlssink location=junk2.%05d.ts playlist-location=junk2.m3u8
```

Comment: Thank you @Florian. Worked as you suggested. Interesting side note: I remind myself to be sure to clear cache or change filenames when fixing format issues otherwise the new files won't be loaded on refresh.

Comment: Oh yeah, Safari's caching is not helpful when tracking down these kind of issues..